# .DATA file conversion

Tags: r, excel

I have a .data file which contains some data. One dataset is available in 10 rows when I open it in excel. [image] I have manually transposed 1 dataset. Is there a way to do this using Excel or R? I have 500 such records in the .DATA file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are too many details missing to give you an exact answer, but the task is achievable in R. Please share a copy of one of your .DATA files and you'll receive usable answers. Below is some untested code which I believe would work based on your description.

```
setwd("C:\\Users\\...Path to your data")

DataFileNames <- list.files(pattern="\\.data$")
Datafiles <- lapply(DataFileNames, read.table, sep="\t")
Transposed <- lapply(Datafiles, t)
lapply(1:length(Datafiles), function(x) write.table(Transposed[x], DataFileNames[x]))
```